# warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast with pointers to structs

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I've been getting this `warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast` in my fifo() function of the following file. Maybe somebody can help me figure out why.

I have a list.c file that defines a very simple list functionality, and several other files that call on the list. Here is one such file.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "vm.h"

struct Node *head = NULL;

int fifo() {
  int next = list_item_at_head(head);
  head = list_remove_head(head); // warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
  list_insert_tail(head, next);
  return next;
} // fifo
```

Here are the relevant parts from list.c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include "list.h"

struct Node* list_remove_head(struct Node *head) {

  if(head == NULL) return NULL;

  struct Node *ret = head;
  head = head->next;
  head->prev = NULL;
  --list_size;

  return head;
} // list_remove_head
```

and the struct definition in list.h:

```
struct Node  {
  int data;
  struct Node* next;
  struct Node* prev;
}; // Node
int list_size;
int list_item_at_head(struct Node *head);
struct Node* list_new_node(int x);
struct Node* list_insert_head(struct Node *head,int x);
struct Node* list_insert_tail(struct Node *head,int x);
struct Node* list_remove_head(struct Node *head);
struct Node* list_remove_tail(struct Node *head);
struct Node *list_remove(struct Node *head, int data);
void list_print(struct Node *head);
void list_reverse_print(struct Node *head);
```

So it certainly seems like `list_remove_head()` returns a `Node*` and it certainly seems like `head` is a `Node*` so why is the compiler telling me I'm making a pointer from an integer?

Comment: replacement.c:18: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast

That's line 18 of replacement.c

Comment: You're missing `#include "list.h"` in the first program.

Comment: God I hate being "that guy" but that's exactly what it was.

Comment: I'm surprised you didn't also get a warning about an implicit declaration of the function.

Comment: I had an issue with the line before it (now I realize also because I hadn't imported list.h)  where I was trying to access `head->next` and couldn't, but when I made `list_item_at_head()` in `list.c` it worked perfectly. I think that's why I didn't double check to see if I'd even imported -- all the functions seemed to have made it over fine.